# Getting an Error as Object Disposed Exception

Tags: c#, testing

```
application.exe

ObjectDisposedException
System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream

at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write()
at CoreLab.Oracle.CoreLab1Oracle.a()
..
```

I need to replicate the issue and I don't understand what causes this error.

Can anyone explain under what conditions this exception is thrown ?

Comment: Keeping detailed description would help you to get the answer quickly, still you may choose to rename the name(s) of your application specific libraries/code to whatever you want, as long as they doesn't mask the actual problem, if you wish to keep them confidential, but details and what you did to find/fix the problem is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more context, all we can tell you is that some code (whatever `CoreLab.Oracle.CoreLab1Oracle.a()` is) tried to `Write` to a `NetworkStream` that had already been disposed. This could be as simple as "a socket became disconnected", or could be more complex involving your usage of the objects, and potentially explicitly calling `Dispose()` (or implicitly via `using`) too early. Or it could just be as simple as "just a bug".

But fundamentally, we can't debug that without a lot more information. Is `CoreLab.Oracle.CoreLab1Oracle` your own code? or some library that you are using?